# Any performance issue for one GlobalKey for each widget?

Tags: flutter, global-key

For a large widget tree with stateful widgets, there is not a way to navigate  widget/state tree from root. The workaround is adding globalKey for each widget, and build a tree of globalKey(s).

```
   Widget0                   GlobalKey0
      Widget1                   GlobalKey1
        Widget1_1                 GlobalKey1_1
        Widget1_2                 GlobalKey1_2
```

With globalKey tree, user inputs can be collected from a subtree, and sent to server.

No moving widgets within tree. One to one mapping between widget/state/element. So there will be no re-parenting. right?

Any performance issue with this approach? Thousands of GlobalKey(s) is expected. When a subtree is rebuild, some new GlobalKey(s) will be created and some will be deleted(not referenced, garbage collected?).

Comment: For one small size table, e.g., 20*20 = 400 widgets(cell). Each table cell can be updated without rebuilding table. So each table cell needs to have a GlobalKey.

Comment: If you don't want a widget to be rebuild just try to use StatelessWidget as much as possible.